# Can you determine who read the contents of a folder in linux?

Tags: linux, file-access

I have a folder that I own, but also has read permissions for the entire group. I would like to know who read/copied the contents and when. Is it possible to do this with a script or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kernel’s audit system](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) can be used for this

Comment: thanks. although I don't have root access for this to work, your answer was nevertheless helpful.